# sql table cell modified by multiple threads at the same time

Tags: sql, multithreading

if you have table **BankAccount** that has a column **Amount** and the value for this column for a specific row can be **modified by multiple threads at the same time** so it could happen so that the last one to set the value will win.

how do you usually handle this kind of situations ?

**UPDATE:** I heard that in MSSQL there is update lock UPDLOCK that locks the table or the row that is being updated, could I this here somehow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An update statement which references the current value would prevent overwriting.  So, instead of doing something like

```
SELECT Amount FROM BankAccount WHERE account_id = 1
```

(it comes back as 350 and you want to subtract 50)...

```
UPDATE BankAccount SET Amount = 300 WHERE account_id = 1
```

do

```
UPDATE BankAccount SET Amount = Amount - 50 WHERE account_id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have several threads modifying the same data at exactly the same time : it will always be the last one which set the value that'll "win".

If the problem is that several threads read and set the value at almost the same time, and reads and writes don't arrive on the right order, the solution is to use [Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) :

- start a transaction
- read the value
- set the new value
- commit the transaction

This ensures the read and the write will be done consistently, and no other thread will be able to modify the data during the same transaction.

Quoting the wikipedia page about [Database Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) :

> A database transaction comprises a
>   unit of work performed within a
>   database management system (or similar
>   system) against a database, and
>   treated in a coherent and reliable way
>   independent of other transactions.
>   Transactions in a database environment
>   have two main purposes:
>
> 1. To provide reliable units of work that allow correct recovery from
>      failures and keep a database
>      consistent even in cases of system
>      failure, when execution stops
>      (completely or partially) and many
>      operations upon a database remain
>      uncompleted, with unclear status.
> 2. To provide **isolation between programs accessing a database
>      concurrently**. Without isolation the
>      programs' outcomes are typically
>      erroneous.

Comment: do I have a lock over this row during the transaction ? I mean if I write a SP that adds +5 to that cell and two threads (one started the transaction during the execution of the first one so the value of the cel was the initial) execute this SP it could happen that the result will be +5 instead of +10 ?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the exact DBMS you are using ; but, in the general situations, the first thread should lock the table or the row for a short instant, and the second thread should wait until the lock is released (or until there's a timeout)

Answer (score 2):

You ussually use **transactions** to overcome this.

Have a look at [Database transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)

Comment: am I gonna have a lock over that table row during a transaction ?

Comment: Any proper database server will take care of the appropriate lock depending on the granularity of your sql call for you, i.e. row lock, page, table lock etc.

Comment: As long as it is done as you say. The OP question left open the possibility that it is a SELECT and THEN UPDATE from 2 threads.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a database function/procedure which makes operations with the "Amount". This function/procedure should return if the operation was succeeded or failed (for example, you want take $1000, but current AMount is only $550, so operation can not be proceede).

Expamle in T-SQL:

```
UPDATE BankAccount SET Amount = Amount - 1000 WHERE BankAcountID = 12345 AND Amount >= 1000
RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

If the amaount was changed, the return value will be 1, otherwise 0.

Know, you can safely run this functions/procedures (in several threads too):

```
DECLARE @Result_01 int, Result_02 int, Result_03 int
EXEC @Result_01 = ChangeBankAccountAmount @BankAcountID = 12345, @Amount = 1000
EXEC @Result_02 = ChangeBankAccountAmount @BankAcountID = 12345, @Amount = 15
EXEC @Result_03 = ChangeBankAccountAmount @BankAcountID = 12345, @Amount = 600, @Amount = -2000
```

**EDIT:**
Whole procedure in T-SQL:

```
CRATE PROC ChangeBankAccountAmount
@BankAccountID int,
@ChangeAmount int,
@MMinAmount int = 0
AS BEGIN
  IF @ChangeAmount >= 0
    UPDATE BankAccount SET Amount = Amount + @ChangeAmount WHERE BankAcountID = 12345
  ELSE
    UPDATE BankAccount SET Amount = Amount + @ChangeAmount WHERE BankAcountID = 12345 AND Amount >= @MMinAmount

  RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Of course - the "int" datatype is not good for money, you should change it to datatype used in your table.

Comment: "Transact-SQL" is the term Microsoft uses for the variant of SQL that Microsoft SQL Server uses, not MSSQL.  (Not a company shill, just pedantic, I promise.)

Comment: MSSQL is shortcut for Microsoft SQL Server product, which uses T-SQL as language. I don't think, the difference between "on MSSQL" and "in T-SQL" is important for this case, however, if you (or somebody else) want, you can change it.

Comment: King of you to invite me to project my pedantry further, but I fear I lack sufficient reputation on SO to have that power just yet.